# How to extend users from other db in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am joining two Django apps and they will have "users" in common both Apps are in different databases.

I was using a routers and everything was working fine but the problem appeared when I was trying to import User from the other db.

My users model looks like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Company"
    verbose_name_plural = "Companies"

def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name


class CompanyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    token = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Users - Company"
    verbose_name_plural = "Users - Company"
```

In my view I have this:

```
from users.models import Company, User

    company = request.user.username #This is fine
    company = request.user.companyuser.company This gives error
```

I am getting this error

```
 **User has no companyuser**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

companyuser is not a user attribute, try the following:

```
company = Company.objects.filter(companyuser__user=request.user)
```

Comment: Beautiful thanks, I just changed `.filter` for `.get` as an user only can have one company... Cheers.